# How to mount react_component from ajax html in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, react-rails

I use this in ruby on rails with react-rails.

In my app ,I want to use ajax to get a html response:

`<%= react_component('Post') %>`

Post Component:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
     render:function(){
          return <div>Article</div>;
     }
})
```

and attach it to App Component:

```
var App = React.createClass({
getInitialState:function(){
    return {html:''};
},
componentDidMount:function(){
    var that = this;
    $.get('/home/component').done(function(data){
        that.setState({html:data});

    });
},
getHtml:function(){
    return { __html:this.state.html};
},
render: function() {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.getHtml()}></div>;
}
});
```

But after that it is fail, which show:

`<div data-react-class="Post" data-react-props="{}"></div>`

I already add post.js app.js to index.html.
How can I mount this to DOM.
Thank.....

Comment: Does the callback in $get run?

Comment: yes. I see it in network console.

Comment: I just add error callback in $get, it goes there, pls check it has a parsing issue!

Comment: thanks, I try it then.

Comment: fyi, I recommend using reactjs-rails with coffeescript, it is more easy to work on, this is my example project, you may take a look https://github.com/phthhieu/reactjs-rails-coffee-example

Comment: So you want to use the html string of the component form an ajax respons?
prerender: true could help with rails 'j' helper I think.